# How to detect events like lock/unlock screen, enter/return suspend and monitor power off

Tags: qt, c++, lock-screen, events

I am wondering if there is any way to detect system wide events under linux such as:

- user un/locked session
- user logs in/out
- machine sent to suspend
- screensaver goes on
- and the monitor switches off due inactivity

I need this for a Qt project where i programmatically react to such events, but i am uncertain how and where to start. Maybe there is an api that i dont know yet.

Any hints? I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
gnome-screensaver-command
```

will give you information about the screen lock events

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"
```

if the command returns any result, then the screen is locked.
You can lock the screen with     `gnome-screensaver-command -l`

Dont have any info abt suspend state

Comment: actually, this only reports if the **screensaver is active** ! The screensaver can be active without it being locked (`-a`) and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dbus API to track this information.

See some examples which use the `dbus-monitor` command are here: [Way to measure computer usage via screensaver active/not active time? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41262/way-to-measure-computer-usage-via-screensaver-active-not-active-time).

E.g.:

```
dbus-monitor 'path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver, member=ActiveChanged'
```

This can also be done directly from c++, in a python program, etc., using the dbus API directly.